# The "\newcommand", with 25 parameters, recursively defined through other "\newcommand" does not work

Tags: macros, recursion, definition

I defined a custom command with 25 parameters with the "newcommand" that I called "commandM".

I am working with block matrices. You need to repeat them in the text with one or two modified entries. I didn't want to have to repeat all the code in a 5 by 5 block matrix at all times in the text. So I made this command with 25 arguments.

[image]

To define "commandM" I used 4 other custom commands defined also with "newcommand". 
They are: "commandA" (with 9 parameters), "commandB" (with 6 parameters), "commandC" (with 6 parameters) and "commandD" (with 4 parameters).

But when I compile the LaTex code, Texmaker 5.0.2 compiles for several minutes and never finish processing the code. It seems to go into Looping. The same happened with TeXstudio 2.12.22. I also tried to compile on overleaf.com and the problem persisted.

The the mimimal exemple of problem is the LaTeX below. Try to make the smallest illustrative example of the problem that I could. But as you can see, it was long.

> Question. How to define a custom command with parameters recursively from several other custom commands (each with several parameters) without the compilation problem described above and working normally?

Thanks in advance.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}
 %\begin{comment}
 \newcommand{\commandA}[9]{
    %parameters
    \def\Aaa{#1}\def\Aab{#2}\def\Aac{#3}
    \def\Aba{#4}\def\Abb{#5}\def\Abc{#6}
    \def\Aca{#7}\def\Acb{#8}\def\Acc{#9}
    %%%
        \left[
        \begin{array}{r r r}
        \Aaa & \Aab  & \Aac \\
        \Aba & \Abb  & \Abc \\
        \Aca & \Acb  & \Acc \\
        \end{array}
        \right]
 }
 $$
 \commandA{A_{11}}{A_{12}}{A_{13}}{A_{21}}{A_{22}}{A_{23}}{A_{31}}{A_{32}}{A_{33}}
 $$
 %\end{comment}
 %\begin{comment}
 \newcommand{\commandB}[6]{
    %parameters
    \def\Baa{#1}\def\Bab{#2}
    \def\Bba{#3}\def\Bbb{#4}
    \def\Bca{#5}\def\Bcb{#6}
    %%%
        \left[
        \begin{array}{r r }
        \Baa & \Bab   \\
        \Bba & \Bbb   \\
        \Bca & \Bcb   \\
        \end{array}
        \right]
   }
   $$
   \commandB{B_{11}}{B_{12}}{B_{21}}{B_{22}}{B_{31}}{B_{32}}
   $$
   %\end{comment}
   %\begin{comment}
    \newcommand{\commandC}[6]{
    %parameters
    \def\Caa{#1}\def\Cab{#2}\def\Cac{#3}
    \def\Cba{#4}\def\Cbb{#5}\def\Cbc{#6}
    %%%
        \left[
        \begin{array}{r r r}
        \Caa & \Cab & \Cac \\
        \Cba & \Cbb & \Cbc  
        \end{array}
        \right]
   }
   $$
   \commandC{C_{11}}{C_{12}}{C_{13}}{C_{21}}{C_{22}}{C_{23}}
   $$
   %\end{comment}
   %\begin{comment}
   \newcommand{\commandD}[4]{
    %parameters
    \def\Daa{#1}\def\Dab{#2}
    \def\Dba{#3}\def\Dbb{#4}
    %%%
        \left[
        \begin{array}{r r}
        \Daa & \Dab  \\
        \Dba & \Dbb 
        \end{array}
        \right]
   }
   $$
   \commandD{D_{11}}{D_{12}}{D_{21}}{D_{22}}
   $$
   %\end{comment}
   $$
   \commandD{\commandA{A_{11}}{A_{12}}{A_{13}}{A_{21}}{A_{22}}{A_{23}}{A_{31}}{A_{32}}{A_{33}}}{\commandB{B_{11}}{B_{12}}{B_{21}}{B_{22}}{B_{31}}{B_{32}}}{\commandC{C_{11}}{C_{12}}{C_{13}}{C_{21}}{C_{22}}{C_{23}}}{\commandD{D_{11}}{D_{12}}{D_{21}}{D_{22}}}
   $$

    %\begin{comment}
    \newcommand{\commandM}[9]{
    %parameters
    \def\Aaa{#1}\def\Aab{#2}\def\Aac{#3}
    \def\Aba{#4}\def\Abb{#5}\def\Abc{#6}
    \def\Aca{#7}\def\Acb{#8}\def\Acc{#9}
    \newcommand{\scommandM}[6]{
    %parameters
    \def\Baa{#1}\def\Bab{#2}
    \def\Bba{#3}\def\Bbb{#4}
    \def\Bca{#5}\def\Bcb{#6}
    \newcommand{\sscommandM}[6]{
    %parameters
    \def\Caa{#1}\def\Cab{#2}\def\Cac{#3}
    \def\Cba{#4}\def\Cbb{#5}\def\Cbc{#6}
    \newcommand{\ssscommandM}[4]{
    %parameters
    \def\Daa{#1}\def\Dab{#2}
    \def\Dba{#3}\def\Dbb{#4}
    %comando 
        \commandD{\commandA{\Aaa}{\Aab}{\Aac}{\Aba}{\Abb}{\Abc}{\Aca}{\Acb}{\Acc}}{\commandB{\Baa}{\Bab}{\Bba}{\Bbb}{\Bca}{\Bcb}}{\commandC{\Caa}{\Cab}{\Cac}{\Cba}{\Cbb}{\Cbc}}{\commandD{\Daa}{\Dab}{\Dba}{\Dbb}}
    }\ssscommandM
    }\sscommandM
    }\scommandM
    }
    $$
      \commandM{Aaa}{Aab}{Aac}{Aba}{Abb}{Abc}{Aca}{Acb}{Acc}{Baa}{Bab}{Bba}{Bbb}{Bca}{Bcb}{Caa}{Cab}{Cac}{Cba}{Cbb}{Cbc}{Daa}{Dab}{Dba}{Dbb}
    $$
    %\end{comment}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: the idea is to post a minimal example that shows the problem you shouldn't include unrelated packages longtable... it just makes it harder for people tracing the code to debug

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hesitated whether to put all the LaTeX code here. But I think there may be a conflict with some package I'm using. So I understood that I must put it all here.

Comment: Is there any real advantage in defining a command with 25 arguments? How do you remember the role of each? What's your aim? It's probably solvable with a less barbaric method.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to define a command with 25 arguments? I normally stop at 4.

Comment: No it is easy for you to test that, You can delete _every_ package in the preamble and show the same problem. Also it would help if you said what you intended this code to do (it is rather strange and convoluted code to expect anyone to guess what it is intended to do)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just a moment. I will improve the question by saying the purpose I intend.

Comment: you added another block but that's just a fragment you can delete the full example and just add `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` to the new one so it can be used.

Comment: but as egreg and Ulrike have said a 25 mandatory `{}` argument interface is just horrible, we can tell you why it's looping (probably) but you wouldn't ever want to use this in a real document

Comment: It seems that you want to solve an unknown problem (said it X) and think that the ideal solution will be  Y(=nested command with endless arguments)  so you ask here to solve Y, but probably your question will be more profitable explaining  X and left people propose  solutions for X, not for Y.

Comment: @Fran I edited my question explaining the purpose of a command with so many parameters. I think this is the "Y" problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a command with 25 mandatory arguments (why not a more usable synatx like a comma separated list of arbitrary length) then you can do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\def\command#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
\def\Aa{#1}%
\def\Ab{#2}%
\def\Ac{#3}%
\def\Ad{#4}%
\def\Ae{#5}%
\def\Af{#6}%
\def\Ag{#7}%
\def\Ah{#8}%
\def\Ai{#9}%
\commandB}
\def\commandB#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
\def\Aj{#1}%
\def\Ak{#2}%
\def\Al{#3}%
\def\Am{#4}%
\def\An{#5}%
\def\Ao{#6}%
\def\Ap{#7}%
\def\Aq{#8}%
\def\Ar{#9}%
\commandC}
\def\commandC#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
\def\As{#1}%
\def\At{#2}%
\def\Au{#3}%
\def\Av{#4}%
\def\Aw{#5}%
\def\Ax{#6}%
\def\Ay{#7}%
\commandD}


\def\commandD{%
something with [\Aa] to [\Ay].%
}

 \begin{document}

\command{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}{12}{13}{14}{15}{16}{17}
{18}{19}{20}{21}{22}{23}{24}{25}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: if you need to nest calls to this then you would need to add some grouping so that the definitions of `A...` do not over-write each other.

Comment: Where is your favorite `z`:)? I mean `\Az`, `\z`, `\zz` etc.

Comment: @wipet every now and then I give Ulrike a chance. It's so hard to find z on a German keyboard:-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want a friendlier syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,blkarray}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\blocks}{mmmm}
 {
  \mo_blocks:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mo_blocks_a_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mo_blocks_b_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mo_blocks_c_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mo_blocks_d_seq
\tl_new:N \l__mo_blocks_i_tl
\tl_new:N \l__mo_blocks_ii_tl
\tl_new:N \l__mo_blocks_iii_tl
\tl_new:N \l__mo_blocks_iv_tl
\tl_new:N \l__mo_blocks_v_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mo_blocks:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_a_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_b_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_c_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_d_seq { ; } { #4 }
  % make the rows
  % 1
  \tl_set:Nx \l__mo_blocks_i_tl
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_a_seq { 1 } , \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_b_seq { 1 } }
  % 2
  \tl_set:Nx \l__mo_blocks_ii_tl
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_a_seq { 2 } , \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_b_seq { 2 } }
  % 3
  \tl_set:Nx \l__mo_blocks_iii_tl
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_a_seq { 3 } , \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_b_seq { 3 } }
  % 4
  \tl_set:Nx \l__mo_blocks_iv_tl
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_c_seq { 1 } , \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_d_seq { 1 } }
  % 5
  \tl_set:Nx \l__mo_blocks_v_tl
   { \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_c_seq { 2 } , \seq_item:Nn \l__mo_blocks_d_seq { 2 } }
  % replace , with &
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_i_tl { , } { & }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_ii_tl { , } { & }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_iii_tl { , } { & }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_iv_tl { , } { & }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__mo_blocks_v_tl { , } { & }
  % make the block matrix
  \left[
  \vcenter{\hbox{$
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
  \begin{block}{[ccc][cc]}
  \smash[b]{\vphantom{\Big|}}
  \tl_use:N \l__mo_blocks_i_tl \\
  \tl_use:N \l__mo_blocks_ii_tl \\
  \smash[t]{\vphantom{\Big|}}
  \tl_use:N \l__mo_blocks_iii_tl \\
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{[ccc][cc]}
  \smash[b]{\vphantom{\Big|}}
  \tl_use:N \l__mo_blocks_iv_tl \\
  \smash[t]{\vphantom{\Big|}}
  \tl_use:N \l__mo_blocks_v_tl \\
  \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  $}\vspace{-2.5ex}}
  \right]
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\blocks{
  1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9
}{
  10,11;12,13;14,15
}{
  16,17,18;19,20,21
}{
  22,23;24,25
}
+\blocks{
  a_{11},a_{12},a_{13};a_{21},a_{22},a_{23};a_{31},a_{32},a_{33}
}{
  b_{11},b_{12};b_{21},b_{22};b_{31},b_{32}
}{
  c_{11},c_{12},c_{13};c_{21},c_{22},c_{23}
}{
  d_{11},d_{12};d_{21},d_{22}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Truly a simple ...long code :-))) ahahah.